# jwt is not installing and give me this error any solution for it?

Tags: jwt, composer-php, php-8.1

└─$ composer require tymon/jwt-auth
Using version ^0.5.12 for tymon/jwt-auth
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update tymon/jwt-auth
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires tymon/jwt-auth ^0.5.12 -> satisfiable by tymon/jwt-auth[0.5.12].
- tymon/jwt-auth 0.5.12 requires illuminate/support ~5.0 -> found illuminate/support[v5.0.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

Comment: `tymon/jwt-auth 0.5.12 requires illuminate/support ~5.0` - that means the package you want to use is only compatible with Laravel v5. Which version do you use?

Comment: Also, why not use v1.0.2 of that package - it is way more uptodate and supports Laravel v5 to v8

Comment: problem has solved thank you so much for answering